# Crear countdown en flask y mostrarlo con html

Tags: html, python, flask, countdowntimer

estoy creando una app y quiero que al dar click en un boton, se genere una cuenta regresiva y que esta se muestre en el html

lo intente con este codigo pero la pagina se queda cargando hasta que finalice el bucle. Como lo podria correr en segundo plano?

```
@app.route('/countdow')
def countdown():
    t = 2340
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1


    context = {
        'timer' : timer
    }


    return render_template('hello.html', **context)
```

y en el html lo mostraria asi

```
<h1>{{timer}}</h1>
```

les agradezco mucho si pudieran ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Tienes un error de concepto. Una petición HTTP solo se envía al cliente cuando la función Flask retorna. Si la función se "entretiene" contando, la página no llega hasta el final (y obviamente el cliente no ve la cuenta). O bien haces la cuenta en el lado cliente usando Javascript, o bien implementas un servicio que use otra tecnología como websockets o SSE para ir enviando al cliente el valor del contador cada vez que se actualice (y el cliente usaría  JS y AJAX para recibir ese contador y actualizarlo en la vista html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración